# Setting table height inside of a cell

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an asp.net application that uses a gridview to create a table. 
The issue I'm having is the height of the table that is embedded inside the td does not have the same height as the td. It only has the height of the content within. How would I get the embedded table to have the same height? 
I've tried applying a heigh of 100% to the table but that does not work.

```
<table cellspacing="0"
style="border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <th scope="col">
        <table>
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">
                    Entertainment
                 </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>TV</td>
                 <td>Computer</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <table style="width:100%; border-spacing: 0;">
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    47
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    47
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cf5w7oLL/3/)**:

CSS:

```
table {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
}

td{
    height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give height to td tag in which table is rendered.
If this doesnt work give height to tr tag just outside td tag in which table is rendered.

```
<table cellspacing="0"
style="border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <th scope="col">
        <table>
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">
                    Entertainment
                 </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>TV</td>
                 <td>Computer</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td style="height:100px">
        <table>
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    47
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    47
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

or

```
<table cellspacing="0"
    style="border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2">
                        Entertainment
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>TV</td>
                     <td>Computer</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height:100px">
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        47
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        47
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```